# How can i pass variables between two projects in same solution with different namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The first project namespace is: namespace EDSDKLib and then the class is: public class SDKHandler : IDisposable

Inside this class i have a method:

```
public void DownloadImage(IntPtr ObjectPointer, string directory)
        {
            EDSDK.EdsDirectoryItemInfo dirInfo;
            IntPtr streamRef;
            //get information about the image
            Error = EDSDK.EdsGetDirectoryItemInfo(ObjectPointer, out dirInfo);
            string CurrentPhoto = Path.Combine(directory, dirInfo.szFileName);
            //create a filestream for the image
            Error = EDSDK.EdsCreateFileStream(CurrentPhoto,
            EDSDK.EdsFileCreateDisposition.CreateAlways, EDSDK.EdsAccess.ReadWrite, out streamRef);
            uint blockSize = 1024 * 1024;
            uint remainingBytes = dirInfo.Size;
            //download the image data in blocks
            do
            {
                if (remainingBytes < blockSize) { blockSize = (uint)(remainingBytes / 512) * 512; }
                remainingBytes -= blockSize;
                Error = EDSDK.EdsDownload(ObjectPointer, blockSize, streamRef);
            } while (remainingBytes > 512);
            //download the last bit of the image
            Error = EDSDK.EdsDownload(ObjectPointer, remainingBytes, streamRef);
            //tell the camera that the download is done
            Error = EDSDK.EdsDownloadComplete(ObjectPointer);
            //release image and stream
            Error = EDSDK.EdsRelease(ObjectPointer);
            Error = EDSDK.EdsRelease(streamRef);
        }
```

Once the image is downloaded to the hard disk i want to use a bool variable not sure yet where in the method DownloadImage after the EdsRelease lines.
For example a bool variable that will be called Saved and in the end to set it to true: Saved = true;

Then i have another project.
This project namespace is: WinFormsUI And the main form: public partial class MainForm : Form

In this form i want to check the Saved bool variable from the other project.
For example to run a timer with interval of a second and to check every second if the variable Saved it true.

Once it's true stop the timer do something and set the variable Saved to false again and start the timer again.

This is how it should look like in the MainForm i think:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          if (Saved == true)
          {
              timer1.Stop();
              // Do something
              Saved = false;
              timer1.Start();
          }
        }
```

The problem is how do i pass and use the Saved variable between the projects.
So i can check if it's true in MainForm and when i set it back to false in the MainForm it will take effect also in the EDSDKLib so it will not stay there true also.

Comment: What are the two project types? If one of them is a Class Library, then it can be referenced in your WinForms project. If they're both executables, you'll need to use some sort of IPC (Inter-Process Communication) mechanism.

Comment: The EDSDKLib project is Class Library and the second is winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SDKHandler` you need to add a static public property named `Saved` of type `bool`.  In your WinForms form you need to check for `SDKHandler.Saved = true` and set `SDKHandler.Saved = false` after processing in the `Tick` event handler.